# Cannot delete AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buckets

I am working with AWS Java SDK. So I played aroung with S3 and now I am having the following situation:
a bucket is shown in my AWS Explorer, also if I retriev

```
s3.listBuckets().size();
```

I get a the size 1. However if I try to list it or delete it I got the error message:

```
Error Message:    Status Code: 404, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 7460661100EAA61B, AWS Error Code: NoSuchBucket, AWS Error Message: The specified bucket does not exist
HTTP Status Code: 404
AWS Error Code:   NoSuchBucket
Error Type:       Client
Request ID:       7460661100EAA61B
```

Comment: Check the region you are trying to delete.

Comment: The ednpoint is the same. It is not only if I ty to delete it but also if I try to acces if like: s3.listObjects(bucket.getName()); I get the same error, its like it is listed somewhere but does not really exist anymore...

Comment: Leave it for a while and it will go away. If not, create it again and delete it again. It is just that your bucket list doesn't sync with the backend AWS server.

Answer (score 0):

I now assume my bucket deletion did not work correctly, 'cause now I just created a bucket with the same name and deleted it again... this worked out form me.